# Calculate the area between functions

Tags: functions, trigonometry, area

[I need to find the area between this three functions, therefore I need to use Integral g(x)-f(x) but I tried and it gives me negative and enormous numbers.]

[image: These are the functions]

[image]

Comment: Please define "area between three functions" ... could we see them at least?

Comment: Sorry I deleted it by mistake, here it is. Hope you can help me.

Comment: There are multiple areas that can be calculated here. Between which x values are you trying to find the area?

Comment: Okay, working on it.

Comment: Looking at your graph there is a clear interior area. You need one integral from $x=0$ to $x=8$ and another from $x=8$ to a point a point near $x=30$. Can you write the two integrals?  Can you find the upper limit of the second, which is the point the two graphs meet?

Comment: I want to calculate the pink area @OriginalOldMan

Comment: @CristinaPimentel Please see my answer.

Comment: @MathMajor thank you very much! It is really helpful

Comment: Your values $29.8, 7.4$ are approximate.  On this site, when you write $=$ you mean $=$.  Finding the intersection point is solving a quadratic.  You should report the correct values.  -1 for that.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche It was a typo :-). I deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you mean by "area between three functions" is, "the area bounded by the three functions".

To compute the area $R$, we will make use of multiple integrals.

First, we will find the intersection of the blue line with the green line. Substitution of $y=2$ into $x=4y$ reveals that $x=8$, as shown in the graph.

Next, we will find the intersection of the red line with the blue:

Direct substitution of $x=4y$ into $y=f(x)$ gives $y=\sqrt{4y}+2$ with solution $y=4+2\sqrt{3}$. Hence, $x=4y=16+8\sqrt{3}$.

Equipped with the above information, we have

$$R=\int_0^8 f_1(x)\, dx+\int_8^{16+8\sqrt{3}} f_2(x) \, dx$$

where $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ represent the difference of the top function and the bottom function in each interval, respectively. I will leave the computations to you.